# CSS menu link background doesn't stay when hovering the drop menu

Tags: html, css, menu

Whenever I hover on the menu item, it turns on the hover background + opens up drop down menu. 
but whenever I hover the dropdown, the background goes off?

[examples](http://gyazo.com/20c9ea451a8c2802d80229d5b2bd7af3.png) and how should it look like [this](http://gyazo.com/e25aa288d19264ca019caf16ac8d97c7.png)

see [Live preview](http://www.justxp.plutohost.net/survive/index.html)

Also as you see the box shadow goes over it.

Codes:
My menu html:

```
       <div class="secondheader">

      <div class="container">

               <div class="span12">

                          <ul class="nav6">

                          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                           <li class="dropdown1"><a href="#">Categories</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="substyle"><a href="#">Buy</a></li>
                    <li class="substyle"><a href="#">Sell</a></li>
                    <li class="substyle"><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
                    <li class="substyle"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="substyle"><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                    <li class="substyle"><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
                    <li class="substyle"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="substyle"><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

                          <li><a href="#">Buy</a></li>

                          <li><a href="#">Sell</a></li>

                          <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>

                          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

                          <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>

                          <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>

                          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

                          <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>

                          </ul>

                          </div>

               </div>

       </div>

</div>
```

My css of menus:

```
.nav6  {
list-style: none;
font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
float: left
font-size: 20px;
margin-top: 13px;
margin-left: -35px;
}
.nav6>li>ul{
display:none;
position:absolute;
background:white;
overflow:hidden;
width: 150px;
background: #fbf2d3;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: -3px;
-webkit-box-shadow:  0px 1px 5px 0px #dadada;
box-shadow:  0px 1px 5px 0px #dadada;       
}
.nav6>li:hover>ul {
display:block;
}
.nav6 >li {
display: inline;
margin: 0px;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
float: left;
margin-top: 10px;
}
.substyle {
padding: 10px;
}
.substyle:hover {
background: #f54922;
padding: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
color: #fff;
}
.subsyle a:hover {
color: #fff;
}
.nav6>li>a {
padding-top: 20px;

padding-bottom: 20px;

padding-left: 20px;

padding-right: 20px;

}
.nav6 a{color: #7D7253;}

.nav6 a:hover {
color: #fff;

text-decoration: none;
}
.nav6 > li > a:hover {
background-image: url("../img/hoverbg.png");    
}
```

Question: What does > selectors do exactly? could you please explain me that with an easy example? thank you very much!

Comment: My antivirus software is telling me that visiting the live preview site might not be such a good idea. Any idea why?

Comment: I think it is my hosting, I've no idea why it does that, but I'm going to ticket about it.

My hosting providers are Plutohosting.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a class that shows the hover image when you're hovered on the whole li, not just the child li. Try changing your last style to this:

```
.nav6 > li > a:hover, .nav6 > li:hover > a {
    background-image: url("../img/hoverbg.png");    
}
```

Also, the > selector is saying specifically a "direct child" of the parent. So if you have this:

```
<div>
    <p><span></span></p>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Then this will apply to all the spans:

```
div span {}
```

This will apply to only the second span:

```
div > span {}
```

Either of these will apply to only the first span:

```
div p span {}
div > p > span {}
```

In the last case, you wouldn't use the > - only use it if you specifically need to target only the direct child.

Comment: Worked thanks!

And currently I want only white text only when hovering drop down menu item, but I set hover for it but it just ignores it, and if I change the overall hover color, it will show the same hover color for the whole menu, how do I fix? thank you

Comment: Glad it's sorted :) I have made many menus like this, they can be fiddly!

Comment: thank you mate! was wondering why it didnt have any vote ups, very clean

Answer (score 0):

Go to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com) for overall knowledge of selectors
and if interested in serious learning you can go to 
[saylor](http://www.saylor.org) for a free education.

FYI think of `>` as meaning within
So, `.nav6>li`  means list "within" the nav6 class

Comment: Please never _ever_ recommend W3Schools - it's full of bad code and incorrect practices.

Answer (score 0):

You just make the changes in your this class `.nav6 > li > a:hover {}`

and write into this format `.nav6 > li:hover a {}`

and this will work fine...........